# WSO2 IOTS: Store device data to RDMS

Tags: wso2, iot

sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to store device data in RDMS. I've changed:

```
<url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/customdeviceDM_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</url>
```

to

```
<url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customdeviceDM_DB</url>
```

and change user name, password, mysql driver installed too.
but it is not working. I tried to create table manually, but I can't create new device. Please help and thanks.

Comment: Hi can u confirm that the table is been created in customdeviceDM_DB database. Also can you provide the log that is printed when you try to create a new device. The log can be found at <IOT_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log

Comment: [Carbon Logs here](http://pastebin.com/PF65pM3K) , I created database and created this table by hand. Still don't work

Comment: Can you check in your MySQL server that the database name is - **customdevicedm_db** because as per the logs it seems like the database name is not matching.

Comment: no, I checked, it's same

Comment: As per the log, your database name is incorrect, in line number 2, you can find some white space and then there is the ending quote for the db name.  Could you please also share the full configurations?